# Filter by RefinableString property does not show up in Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-search, verticals

I have a problem that filters based on RefinableString property does not show up.
I configured such filter for the organization level in the Admin center.

1. 1st of all I went to the Sharepoint Search Schema and mapped the crawled property to the managed one:

[image]

2. then I went to admin > settings > search&intelligence > customizations > verticals > added the filter to my vertical (actually, non of these filter are shown):

[image]

3. Here is the screenshot of the vertical without filters:

[image]

I have reindexed the site -> did not help

I also have a colleague who configured filters with refinableString (under the Managed Search Schema, because it was for Sharepoint site only) as well for the separate site a few weeks ago. And none of the filters are shown.

Could you please kindly advice what can be done in this case?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Found out the solution
I clicked reindex under the library settings.
Once I click on reindex under the Sharepoint settings all filters appeared.

I followed the steps below:
once loggin into the Sharepoint go to site settings > Search and offline avaliability > reindex > ok

[image]